# Acceder a un Atributo repetido en un archivo XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, xml

Buen dia, Actualmente esto trabajando con un archivo XML en lenguaje C#. Lo que necesito es obtener un atributo que se llama: `<string>https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/app/v2?vid=120260023Yae9f6d5abad74f3Ybace72574a779be</string>` El problema es que cuando recorro el nodo e intento buscar ese atributo me encuentro que existen dos con el mismo nombre y siempre obtengo solamente el primero. Quisiera saber como puedo obtener el atributo `<string>https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/app/v2?vid=120260023Yae9f6d5abad74f3Ybace72574a779be</string>` que es el que realmente necesito.

```
<extraParameters>
    <entry>
        <string>EXPIRATION_DATE</string>
        <date>2020-07-24T23:59:59</date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>REFERENCE</string>
        <int>120260023</int>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>URL_PAYMENT_RECEIPT_PDF</string>
        <string>https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/receipt?vid=120260023Yae9f6d5abad74f3Ybace72574a779be</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>URL_PAYMENT_RECEIPT_HTML</string>
        <string>https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/app/v2?vid=120260023Yae9f6d5abad74f3Ybace72574a779be</string>
    </entry>
</extraParameters>
```

Anexo codigo con el cual obtengo informacion:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.LoadXml(data);

                       //    Console.WriteLine(data);

                        //manipulando el xml que arroja el sistema
                        //vamos a conocer el status que arroja el sistema

                        string Code = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("paymentResponse/code").InnerText;
                        string Status = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("paymentResponse/transactionResponse/state").InnerText;

                        //lo siguiente para tomar los html de pago
                        // get a list of all <Contact> nodes
                        XmlNodeList listOfExtraParameters = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("paymentResponse/transactionResponse/extraParameters/entry");

                        foreach (XmlNode singleParameter in listOfExtraParameters)
                        {
                            //necesito obtener el segundo atributo string
                            string StringValue = singleParameter["string"].InnerText;

                            Console.WriteLine("Valor del String: " + StringValue);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria en lugar de parsear el xml que lo deserialices

Entonces defines la entidad

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="entry")]
public class Entry {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="string")]
    public List<string> String { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="int")]
    public string Int { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="extraParameters")]
public class ExtraParameters {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="entry")]
    public List<Entry> Entry { get; set; }
}
```

Y puede deserializarla

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string _xml = @"<extraParameters>
                            <entry>
                                <string>EXPIRATION_DATE</string>
                                <date>2020-07-24T23:59:59</date>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <string>REFERENCE</string>
                                <int>120260023</int>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <string>URL_PAYMENT_RECEIPT_PDF</string>
                                <string>https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/receipt?vid=120260023Yae9f6d5abad74f3Ybace72574a779be</string>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <string>URL_PAYMENT_RECEIPT_HTML</string>
                                <string>https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/app/v2?vid=120260023Yae9f6d5abad74f3Ybace72574a779be</string>
                            </entry>
                        </extraParameters>";
        
        ExtraParameters result = null;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExtraParameters));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(_xml))
        {
           result = (ExtraParameters)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }


        foreach(var entry in result.Entry){
            foreach(var prop in entry.String){
                Console.WriteLine(prop);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Como veras hay listas de elementos, tienes `entry` y dentro de esta tienes `string`

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a interpretar un archivo XML, tienes que tener en cuenta que un nodo puede tener o bien nodos internos o texto además de atributos. Con el método `InnerText` obtienes el contenido del nodo en formato de texto.

Si quieres obtener los atributos de un nodo, utiliza la colección de atributos de ese nodo, por ejemplo, si el objeto de nodo que has leído se llama `node`, puedes utilizar este código para leer sus atributos:

```
foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(attribute.InnerText);
```